# How to use LiveData into ViewModel in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

In my application I want to use **Viewmodel** with **LiveData** and for this I used this tutorial : [ViewModel with LiveData](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#3)

But I have one question, why used **LiveData** such as below :

```
private val _flavor = MutableLiveData<String>("")
val flavor: LiveData<String> = _flavor

fun setFlavor(desiredFlavor: String) {
    _flavor.value = desiredFlavor
}
```

Why not used with below formed?

```
val flavor = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun setFlavor(desiredFlavor: String) {
    flavor.value = desiredFlavor
}
```

Please say me more information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why not used with below formed ?

```
val flavor = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun setFlavor(desiredFlavor: String) {
    flavor.value = desiredFlavor
}
```

**In short, it violates encapsulation.**

Suppose `setFlavor` was more complicated:

```
fun setFlavor(desiredFlavor: String) {
    flavor.value = complextLogicToValidateAndTransform(desiredFlavor)
}
```

You would always want anything trying to update the flavor to go through `setFlavor`. But with an exposed `MutableLiveData` object, anyone can change the flavor and bypass your checks.

```
viewModel.flavor.setValue(unvalidatedAndUntransformedFlavorThatWillCauseHavok)
```

By keeping that private and an only exposing a read-only variable, you control how the value can be updated.

Comment: Although interestingly, if you were to use `databinding` and `two-way binding` then you'd have to expose `MutableLiveData` as `MutableLiveData` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The [MutableLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData) class, publicly exposes [setValue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData#setValue(T)) and [postValue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData#postValue(T)) methods. This means the `value` property can be changed. On the other hand, the [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData) class also contains both methods, but both are set as `protected`. This means that the value cannot be changed.

Why is it necessary to use:

```
private val _flavor = MutableLiveData<String>("")
val flavor: LiveData<String> = _flavor
```

Inside the ViewModel class? It is because the ViewModel class is a bridge between a repository class, where you actually get the data from an API, and the views. So this is the only place where you should change the value. As soon as you assign a value, you save the MutableLiveData object into a LiveData, and you expose it so it can observed from the activity or fragment.